# cURL trouble with getting post response

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to create a basic login program that's connected to server but when I try to save the response from a post request to a variable I wont get a response at all but if I don't try to save it I do get a response, I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated, cheers.

```c++
int post(string str1, string str2, string str3) {

    string query = "user=" + str1 + "&pass=" + str2;

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.vlone.cc/pwned.php");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, query.c_str());

        // when i comment out these 2 lines I get a response otherwise I don't
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_to_string);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &str3);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Write to string

```c++
size_t write_to_string(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t count, void *stream) {
    ((string*)stream)->append((char*)ptr, 0, size*count);
    return size*count;
}
```

Comment: You probably did something wrong in your write callback... which code you don't show here so we can't really tell!

Comment: @DanielStenberg Added it

Comment: my guess is that you're passing in `&str3` to `curl_easy_setopt`. That's the address-of-the-copy-of the parameter you passed in to your `post` function. That parameter won't exist when `post` returns.

If you instead pass `string * str3ptr` into `post` and pass `strptr` to `curl_easy_setopt` and modify your callback, it could work better.

Comment: @Adam.at.Epsilon now I'm getting a Segmentation fault 11

Comment: @pwned you will also have to modify your callback function. Check for type correctness of your `curl_easy_setopt` and `append` function calls. Alternatively use a graphical debugger which produces a stacktrace, like DDD if you're on Linux.